# Import multiple list variables

Tags: python

I currently have a text file with the following format:

```
    b0=[ 1 2 3
         4 5 6
         7 8 9];
    b1=[ 1.1 2.2 3.3
         4.4 5.5 6.6
         -1  -2 -3];
    ...
    b100=[ 1.1 2.2 3.3
         4.4 5.5 6.6
         -1  -2 -3];
```

How can I load all these parameters into a single python variable (something like the varible tmp)?

```
    tmp = [[ 1 2 3 4 5 6], [ 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 -1 -2 -3], ... ]
```

Comment: Oh my. Why are these lists stored like this? Why not just use pickle or json?

Comment: You might benefit from the dupe.

Comment: this file is as is. generated by an old modeling program.